# Execute command in bash for a set of corresponding file names

Tags: bash

I have a directory with lots of config files in it, they look like this:

us-sfo-building1.foo us-sfo-building1.bar
mx-mex-building15.foo mx-mex-building15.bar

Now, I want to execute a script which takes us-sfo-building1.foo and us-sfo-building1.bar as input parameters.

I want basically this: ./script $*.foo $*.bar but I have to make sure that I always have the matching pair of foo and bar, otherwise the script complains. I tried this, but it did not work as expected:

```
#/bin/bash
for x in "*.foo*; do
 x=${x%.foo}
 if [ -e "$x.bar" ]; then
 ./script "$x.foo" "$x.bar"
 fi
done
```

Any idea on how to solve this or where my mistake is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for x in "*.foo*; do` doesn't need a `"`.

**Fix:**

```
#/bin/bash
for x in *.foo; do
  x=${x%.foo}
  if [ -e "$x.bar" ]; then
    ./script "$x.foo" "$x.bar"
  fi
done
```

**And a suggestion (includes preferred use of `[[ ]]`):**

```
#/bin/bash
for x in *.foo; do
  y=${x%.foo}.bar
  [[ -e $y ]] && ./script "$x" "$y"
done
```